# What is the fastest and easiest way of generating a report on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need my App to generate a report which can be emailed.  It must be in some common format e.g. PDF or Excel or CVS.

It does not necessarily have to be graphical...it could just be text.

What is the easiest and fastest way of doing this, I am even willing to use an open source SDK or purchase one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you search stackoverflow or the web already for people talking about doing something similar?

I did, and here's some Q+As I found about generating PDFs:

[PDF generation using data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864597/pdf-generation-using-data)

Excel:

[Generate a spreadsheet file on iOS that is readable both by Excel and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804834/generate-a-spreadsheet-file-on-ios-that-is-readable-both-by-excel-and-numbers)

CSV:

[How to export data to a csv file with iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159576/how-to-export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-iphone-sdk-3-0)